# react native while come back to previous screen the page data is not updated

Tags: react-native

I did some changes in my second screen and comeback to my first screen the data is not updated. After reloading app the data is updated. How to update the data from second screen to first screen navigation without refresh or reload

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i believe without any code is that if you do navigation.goBack() or navigation.navigate() it doesnt call the api if its in your componentDidMount, what you can try is adding an eventlistener called onFocus so that whenever screen is focused you call that :

like  this in your componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){

this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Calling  action to reset current day index to 1

      this.getItineryData();
    });

}
```

Hope it helps